# How to save html output to .java file from php

Tags: php

This is my html output. from .php file

```
public class Resource {

    public static int cliamer = fgfgfger;
    public static int reporting = grgrging;

}
```

I want to save this to mytext.java how is it possible with php

Comment: You should look into [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: fwrite? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: file_put_contents is extremly simple I think. http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$myData = "java code goes here";
$fp = fopen('dir/mytext.java', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $myData);
fclose($fp);
```

Main point of failure here will be the folder's permission.

Comment: To make it nice: `fclose($fp);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 // beginning of your script
 ob_start();

 // your script

 // end of your script
 $data = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean(); // or ob_end_flush(); if you also want to output something
 file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/mytext.java', $data);
```